# JSON geo-point mapping with fields not matching Elasticsearch documentation format

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch, and I'm trying to visualize some JSON data with Kibana.  The trouble I have is with the geo-point mapping format.

The JSON object containing the relevant location fields (lon/lat) looks like this:

```
  "geoNetwork": {
    "city": "Test City",
    "cityId": "1234567",
    "continent": "Americas",
    "country": "Canada",
    "latitude": "44.1234",
    "longitude": "-63.6940",
    "metro": "(not set)",
    "networkDomain": "bellaliant.net",
    "networkLocation": "bell aliant regional communications inc.",
    "region": "Nova Scotia",
    "subContinent": "Northern America"
  },
```

This does not match geo-point format in the Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html, first example), as longitude and latitude are not the only two keys in the geoNetwork (location) object.

Is there a way to define the geo-point mapping so that I can use the JSON as-is, or would I have to modify the JSON schema to have an object that matches one of the geo-point formats in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly what you are asking is impossible :(

Elasticsearch **require** a GeoPoint/GeoLocation/... for any geographic operation.

So from there, I would **recommend updating your json** with a new **GeoPoint** field.

If for some technical reason, this is not possible, while I haven't used them myself, I would lookup **elasticsearch ingestion pipeline**. It act similarly to a SQL trigger. You will be able to add new fields dynamically before the index process, meaning that you can create on insertion a new GeoPoint field from your latitude, longitude field.

**GeoPoint**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

**Ingestion Pipeline**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html